# error in configuring pjsip for android

Tags: android, pjsip

i want to configure pjsip for android.
I have downloaded it from http://www.pjsip.org/download.htm
And following the steps given in http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android
I have successfully executed export and ./configure-android command
But when I excute `make dep && make clean && make` it's giving following errors:

```
$ make dep && make clean && make
for dir in pjlib/build pjlib-util/build pjnath/build third_party/build pjmedia/build pjsip/build pjsip-apps/build ; do \
        if make  -C $dir dep; then \
            true; \
        else \
            exit 1; \
        fi; \
done
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/d/pj/pjproject/pjlib/build'
make -f /cygdrive/d/pj/pjproject/build/rules.mak APP=PJLIB app=pjlib depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/d/pj/pjproject/pjlib/build'
.pjlib-arm-unknown-linux-androideabi.depend:1: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/d/pj/pjproject/pjlib/build'
Makefile:75: recipe for target `depend' failed
make[1]: *** [depend] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/d/pj/pjproject/pjlib/build'
Makefile:14: recipe for target `dep' failed
make: *** [dep] Error 1
```

please help me to configure this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Please, note that building with `cygwin` is not currently supported by `pjsip`: [linux reqs](http://www.pjsip.org/using.htm#gnu_req) because of a problem with Windows headers)

Specifically, your problem is that `make dep` checks all source files per module and annotates all dependencies in a `.module_name.dep` file, if file's path contains a colon (e.g. E**:**//my_path) confuses `make` that sees it as a new target definition, dumping the error that you see: "multiple target patterns" (dep and my_path).

I would strongly recommend using a native Linux computer or, if not possible, `mingw` (not sure if it works)

Comment: I'm using ubuntu server on vmware. make dep still producing above error.